# Vertical and Horizontal Asymptote Lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the vertical asymptote line and horizontal asymptote line of $y=1-\frac{1}{x}$?

I have gotten the vertical asymptote line to be $x=0$ and the horizontal asymptote line to be $y=o$ but when I tried to graph this I started having trouble because when you put $1$ as an $x$-intercept, the $y$-intercept is $0$.

I am confused and could really use an explanation and/or the correct answer as opposed to mine.

Comment: I believe that the horizontal asymptote of the line is y=1, since that is the maximum value of the function (and minimum, for negative values of x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical asymptote occurs when the y value goes to $\infty$. What x value can make the y value very large (either toward $\infty$ or $-\infty$)? As x tends toward $0$, we can see that the y value heads toward $\infty$ or $-\infty$. The vertical asymptote is at $x=0$.

The horizontal asymptote occurs when the x value tends toward $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Let's see what would happen if x goes to $\infty$.
$$y=1-\frac{1}{\infty}$$
$\frac{1}{\infty}$ pretty much equals $0$. Think about it: if x equals $1000000$, then $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{1000000}$, which is very close to $0$. If x equals infinity, then $\frac{1}{x}$ is as close to $0$ as you can get.
$$y=1-0$$
$$y=1$$
Therefore the y asymptote is at $y=1$, and **not** $y=0$

**Edit:** Just to make it clear, you cannot cross vertical asymptotes. However, you *can* cross horizontal asymptotes. For example, take the graph of $f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}$ below:

[image: Horizontal Asymptote Crossing]

The horizontal asymptote is $y=0$, but the graph crosses the horizontal asymptote at $x=2$.

How would one determine if the graph crosses the asymptote or not, and where? You can set $f(x)$ equal to the asymptote, and solve for $x$ In this case, set $f(x)=0$
$$0=\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}$$
$$0=x-2$$
$$x=2$$
We can see that the graph will cross the horizontal asymptote at $x=2$.

Hope I helped!

BTW, the way I obtained the graph above was through an app called "Free Graphing Calculator" made by William Jockusch on the apple store.